# QT: Resizing a QImage with scaled

Tags: qt

Trying to resize an image:

```
size_t targetWidth = funnyImage.get_width();
size_t targetHeight = funnyImage.get_height();
QString inputWidth = 400;
QString inputHeight = 900;

QImage *jpgImage = new QImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, QImage::Format_RGB32);

QImage small = jpgImage->scaled(inputWidth, inputHeight,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

I get this error:

**cpp:125: error: no matching function for call to 'QImage::scaled(QString&, QString&, Qt::AspectRatioMode)'**

> SOLUTION: 
>       QImage small = jpgImage->scaled(inputWidth.toUInt(), inputHeight.toUint,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

Posting it here, because the wonderful reflection made me think.

Comment: @webclectic No, the code won't compile, as it's just some idea on how the structure was, for getting the help.

"[...] very new to QT/C" - Both! Completely fresher to QT AND C++, and happy about doing my first steps. I would have been very happy to find this answer here when I was looking for it. Yes, I read the manual, but as a fresher, I didn't know where to look. Happens more than you think...

Answer (score 14):

Solution:

```
QImage small = jpgImage->scaled( inputWidth.toUInt(), inputHeight.toUInt(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when needing to scaling my window using Qt5.

```
QImage small = jpgImage->scaled(size());
```

works so much better than the proposed solution, as size() takes only in account the usable area. On the contrary, using `height()` and `width()` seems to not take into account the pixels used in the border/menu area.